# Run MatConvNet on CPU with maximum number of workers

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

I wish to run MatConvNet on CPU (no GPU at all), with 44 number of workers in parallel computing. Which part of the codes should be modified? Any help is highly appreciated.